# Cannot find Canon LBP3050 driver for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

I just installed the ubuntu 12.04, and trying to get my printer to work. In fact, I have been following the documentation and googled several pages, but still have not been successful with the issue. It seems that I need to find the Canon Linux CAPT driver version. However, as instructed, from this link...

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CanonCaptDrv190

It seems that the download link to the driver is not dead. Is there a way to find this driver file?

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://software.canon-europe.com/software/0028622.asp) seems to be the link for european customers but its probably pretty generic. I did notice that your specific device wasn't listed but it seems to be the right proprietary driver.
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10. The steps listed in the following web page solves Canon LBP3050 driver problem. Manual driver installation doesn't work for Device URI as USB. This script add the printer with CCP device URI.

https://github.com/hieplpvip/ubuntu_canon_printer

wget https://github.com/hieplpvip/canon_printer/raw/master/canon_lbp_setup.sh
chmod +x canon_lbp_setup.sh
./canon_lbp_setup.sh